# How to use multi CPU cores to train NNs using caffe and OpenBLAS

Tags: multithreading, machine-learning, neural-network, caffe, openblas

I am learning deep learning recently and my friend recommended me caffe. After install it with OpenBLAS, I followed the tutorial, [MNIST task](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html) in the doc. But later I found it was super slow and only one CPU core was working.

The problem is that the servers in my lab don't have GPU, so I have to use CPUs instead.

I Googled this and got some page like [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/80) . I tried to `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=8` and `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8`. But caffe still used one core.

How can I make caffe use multi CPUs?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you build openblas to use threads?

Comment: @Jeff  I just `make` and `make install`. I found a [page](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/faq#multi-threaded), but it does not say anything about building it to use threads. How can I build it to use threads?

Comment: Read the docs. It's pretty clear.

Comment: @Jeff I have to say I didn't find anywhere mentioned about compile OpenBLAS with any parameters related to `threads`.

Comment: USE_OPENMP=1 is noted in https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/develop/README.md. That's how I always build for threaded usage.

Comment: @Jeff Sadly caffe still use one CPU after I rebuild OpenBLAS with `USE_OPENMP=1` and then rebuild caffe. :(

Comment: What's your system config?

Comment: @Jeff Centos 6.5, 24 core CPU. Did you mean these?

Comment: How do you know Caffe is only using one core?  The temporal resolution of `top` may not be enough to catch `dgemm` in action.  Have you run `gprof` to see if increasing `OMP_NUM_THREADS` affects wall time?

Comment: @Jeff I uninstall and reinstall the whole thing and it works. But even though I can use all the cpu it's still suuuper slow. Well, the good news is that my boss bought a TITAN X for the lab. LOL

Comment: There is an OpenMP version of Caffe on Github that is competitive with the GPU port for some workloads. You might try to find it. Threading GEMM isn't always the best way to make DNN go faster...

Comment: @Jeff please, post link to OpenMP caffe fork.

Comment: @mrgloom See https://github.com/intelcaffe.

Comment: @Jeff what is special about this fork? I can't see any references to openmp.

Comment: @mrgloom Sorry, they are in the process of reworking the OpenMP stuff.  There is https://github.com/intelcaffe/caffe-old/tree/openmp but I suspect you want to watch e.g. https://github.com/intelcaffe/caffe/commits/openmp-conv-relu.

Answer (score 2):

@Karthik. That also works for me. One interesting discovery that I made was that using 4 threads reduces forward/backward pass during the caffe timing test by a factor of 2. However, increasing the thread count to 8 or even 24 results in f/b speed that is less than what I get with OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4.
Here are times for a few thread counts (tested on NetworkInNetwork model).

[#threads] [f/b time in ms]
1   223
2   150
4   113
8   125
12  144

For comparison, on a Titan X GPU the f/b pass took 1.87 ms.

Answer (score 1):

While building OpenBLAS, you have to set the flag USE_OPENMP = 1 to enable OpenMP support. Next set Caffe to use OpenBLAS in the Makefile.config, please export the number of threads you want to use during runtime by setting up OMP_NUM_THREADS=n where n is the number of threads you want.

Answer (score -2):

I found that this method works:

When you build the caffe, in your make command, do use this for 8 cores: 
`make all -j8` and
`make pycaffe -j8`

Also, make sure 
        `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=8` 
is set.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395729/how-to-enable-multithreading-with-caffe) question has a full script for the same.

Comment: Just an FYI. Passing -j<number> tells make to invoke up to <number> parallel jobs when building Caffe. It has no effect on Caffe at runtime.