# Can't use multi CPU cores to train NNs using Caffe and OpenBLAS

Tags: conv-neural-network, parallel-processing

I've read this discussion: [How to use multi CPU cores to train NNs using caffe and OpenBLAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195837/how-to-use-multi-cpu-cores-to-train-nns-using-caffe-and-openblas)

My machine has 4 CPUs.

I've set the following variables:

```
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4 
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
```

however it doesn't help:

```
I0314 17:16:21.365342 27054 solver.cpp:229] Iteration 696, loss = 0.727476

I0314 17:17:40.497768 27054 solver.cpp:229] Iteration 697, loss = 0.72481
```

For the comparison here is the result for the case when

```
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1

I0314 17:19:41.242964 30215 solver.cpp:229] Iteration 16, loss = 0.933368

I0314 17:21:04.143072 30215 solver.cpp:229] Iteration 17, loss = 0.772665
```

**one iteration still takes about 80 seconds.**

As I see it, the variables mentioned don't make any effect (the difference in timing can be explained by different load of the machine).
How can I ensure that `OpenBLAS` really does not exploit the 4 CPUs and why?

Comment: Programming issues are off-topic at Cross Validated. In any case, you haven't even indicated what software you are using...

Comment: This should be migrated to stackoverflow?

Comment: I wonder if the [cstheory] site might be a better choice for you.